# Dynamic column selection in insert query - Oracle

Tags: jquery, oracle, dynamic

A table which consists of more than 30 columns. Based on a specific condition need to insert data in different colums.

for example, Suppose table **tbl_Testdata** contains 
 "Id","name", **"string_col","numeric_col"** .

And my input parameter contains 
 *"A","TEST" then, this should be added in string col.
 *"b",5 then, this should be added in numeric_col.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Use [Dynamic SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/dynamic.htm#LNPLS011) to construct your query as a simple VARCHAR2 or CLOB.

Then just execute it with `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`.

Answer (score -1):

SQL> Create table program (p_name varchar2(20), p_date date);

Table created.

SQL> Insert into program values('PROGRAM_1', date '2019-02-03');

1 row created.

SQL> Insert into program values('PROGRAM_1', date '2019-03-03');

1 row created.

SQL> COMMIT;

Commit complete.

SQL>

Hope, This will help you.....

Comment: Sorry but this does not provide anything which is relevant to the OP's situation. They are trying to **generate** DML statements from metadata